# iPad Doesn't Render H.264 Video with HTML5

Tags: ios, ipad, html, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have some H.264-encoded videos which render in HTML5 correctly in the web browser, but do not render correctly on the iPad.  When I use a H.264 video I downloaded off the internet, my video renders correctly on the iPad, so it is not an HTML problem.

Here is the ffmpeg info about my videos --

My original .mov video:

> Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 6000.00 (6000/1) -> 30.00 (30/1)
>
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a_video.mp4':
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
> major_brand     : qt  
> minor_version   : 537199360
> compatible_brands: qt
> ```
>
> Duration: 00:00:42.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 220 kb/s
>
> ```
> Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 94 kb/s
> Stream #0.1(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 762x464, 122 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 3k tbn, 6k tbc
> ```

After using Handbrake to convert my .mov to a mp4, yet doesn't render on the iPad:

> Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
>
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a_video.m4v':
>
> Metadata:
>
> ```
> major_brand     : mp42  
> minor_version   : 0
> compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1  
> encoder: HandBrake 0.9.5 2011010300
> ```
>
> Duration: 00:00:42.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 169 kb/s
>
> Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 752x464 [PAR 381:376 DAR 381:232], 35 kb/s, PAR 145161:141376 DAR 145161:87232, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
>      Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s

Here is a .mp4 I found online which does render on the iPad:

> Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
>
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a_video_3_emu.mp4':
>
> Metadata:
>      major_brand     : M4VP
>      minor_version   : 1
>      compatible_brands: M4VPM4A mp42isom
>      encoder         : CoreMediaAuthoring 677, CoreMedia 420.17, i386
>
> Duration: 00:01:38.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1023 kb/s
>
> Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 32000 Hz, mono, s16, 97 kb/s
>      Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 480x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 914 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc

Does anyone see something wrong with the way I am encoded my videos?

**Edit**

At first my theory was that the iPad was sensitive to different container formats; but that appears not to be the case.  I took a video which does render correctly on the iPad and converted it to a .mov, and it *still* played correctly on the iPad.  So there must be a problem with how the iPad deals with the underlying H.264 stream.

Comment: Does the mp4 work when viewing the page on a desktop browser?

Comment: Yes.  This only happens on the iPad.  It has something to do with mp4 vs. m4v.

Comment: I just ran this command on the video that did render on the iPad: ffmpeg -i a_video_3_emu.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4 .  output.mp4 still worked on the iPad.  It looks like it might not be a container issue but the underlying stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a H.264 video stream -- regardless of the container (mov, m4v, mp4) -- and your HTML5 video renders in a web browser but doesn't render on the iPad, there are two possible fixes:

The first solution is to convert the H.264 video stream to mpeg4.

`ffmpeg -i video_h264_not_working.mov -acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4 video_mpeg.mov`

(Alternatively, you can select MPEG4 instead of H.264 in Handbrake.)

The second solution is to re-process the H.264 video with the following parameters:

`ffmpeg -i video_h264_not_working.mov -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -b 516k -bt 516k -crf 22 -vpre normal video_h264.mov`

The second solution came from: http://houseoflaudanum.com/navigate/howtos/html5-video-no-webm/

I'm guessing in the former case, the mpeg4 codec is more relaxed on the iPad; and in the latter case, the iPad didn't like some of the stream parameters from the original H.264 encoding, so a "cleaning" was necessary.

To determine what your video stream actually is, just do ffmpeg -i myvideo.mov.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success encoding and transcoding HTML5 video using the free [**Miro Video Converter**](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) (OS X, Windows) as recommended in the [Video on the Web section of Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html#miro) by Mark Pilgrim.

Miro Video Converter can convert virtually any video file to MP4, Theora, or MP3 (the audio only). It has presets that will convert video to the correct sizes and formats for popular phones, iPods, and other media players. Just convert your video and copy it to your device.

It's a super simple way to convert almost any video to MP4, WebM (vp8), Ogg Theora, or for Android, iPhone, and more. You'll feel good that it's 100% Free and open-source, too.

An another veritable video conversion utility is [**Video Monkey**](http://videomonkey.org/about/), a free video encoding application exclusively for Mac. It was created after the demise of the great tool Visual Hub. Video Monkey borrows heavily from the Visual Hub video conversion tool, both conceptually and from the original code dump posted to SourceForge as TranscoderRedux.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Miro doesn't work.  In fact, when I convert .wmv's to .webm for use with Chrome, it crashes.  (For reference: Handbrake and VLC also don't work with the iPad, but both can produce videos of various formats that work with Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo port install ffmpeg` and try this secret sauce:

```
#!/bin/bash
BR=512k
WIDTH=640
HEIGHT=272
input=${1}

# strip off the file extension
output=$(echo ${input} | sed 's/\..*//' )

# works for most videos
ffmpeg -y -i ${input} -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s ${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT} -vcodec libx264 -b ${BR} -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 0 -refs 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate ${BR} -bufsize ${BR} -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 30 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect ${WIDTH}:${HEIGHT} -g 30 -async 2 ${output}-iphone.ts
```

Adjust width and height to the original video and set the bitrate as you see fit. Pass the original video as parameter to the script. Works with almost any source format. You need [macports](http://www.macports.org/) for the port command.